# What are the factors that affect the response time of a webpage?

Tags: performance, http, testing, https

I'm working on some performance tests on web pages that use the HTTPS protocol, and for me it is still unclear which factors interfere in the page response time. What makes a Web page to respond faster or slower a request from a client?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is for specific questions about actual problems you're experiencing with your code or programming tool. We don't make lists of things regarding things that you might experience for a broad topic. If you have a **specific** question that fits within the [help/on-topic] guidelines here, we can try and help answer it.

Answer (score 0):

20 Top Factors That Impact Website Response Time:
1. COMPLEXITY
2. INTERDEPENDENCIES
3. CONFIGURATION AND COMMUNICATION OF COMPONENTS
4. LATENCY
5. DEMAND PEAKS
6. WEB PAGE SIZE
7. RESPONSIVE WEB DESIGN
8. JAVASCRIPT
9. WEB CONTENT AND CODE
10. N+1 QUERIES
11. THE BACK-END SERVER
12. THE DATABASE
13. THIRD PARTY SERVICES
14. THE NETWORK
15. VIRTUALIZATION
16. IT INFRASTRUCTURE CHANGES
17. ALTERED CODE
18. DISTRIBUTED DENIAL OF SERVICE ATTACKS (DDOS)
19. INFORMATION ARCHITECTURE